# I am Working with Doubly Linked Lists in C and I am Using Turbo C++ but The Compiler is Taking Two Additional Nodes without Adding

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, turbo-c++

I am Working With Doubly Linked List & Implementing Them using C
I am using Turbo C++ as my Compiler
But it's Taking Two Constant Additional Nodes Every Time without Writing Code for It
The Same Code is Running in VS Code
But I Should Run it In Turbo C++
I tried Changing Systems, but it didn't Work

```
'''
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    struct Node *prev;
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;

void insatbeg()
{
    int item;
    struct Node *ptr = NULL;
    printf("\nEnter Item: ");
    scanf("%d", &item);
    ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("\nOverflow Occured");
    else if (head == NULL)
    {
        ptr->data = item;
        ptr->next = ptr->prev = NULL;
        head = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->prev = NULL;
        ptr->data = item;
        ptr->next = head;
        head->prev = ptr;
        head = ptr;
    }
}

void display()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("\nList is Empty");
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int loopvar = 1, switchvar;
    clrscr();
code:
    while (loopvar == 1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter 1 to Insert at First");
        printf("\nEnter 2 to Display");
        printf("\nEnter: ");
        scanf("%d", &switchvar);
        switch (switchvar)
        {
        case 1:
            insatbeg();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nEnter Properly: ");
            goto code;
            break;
        }
        printf("\nDo You Want to Continue: ");
        scanf("%d", &loopvar);
    }
    getch();
}
'''
```

Also the Redundant Nodes Added Always are Constant

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248328/discussion-on-question-by-karthikanurag-i-am-working-with-doubly-linked-lists-in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
```

is invalid. You allocated a memory for the pointer type `struct Node *` while you need to allocate memory for an object of the type `struct Node`. So write

```
ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Also in this code snippet

```
else
{
    ptr->prev = NULL;
    ptr->data = item;
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
}
```

you forgot to set the data member `prev` of the head node. Write

```
else
{
    ptr->prev = NULL;
    ptr->data = item;
    ptr->next = head;
    head->prev = ptr;
    head = ptr;
}
```

Pay attention to that the pointer `temp1` is not used in your program.

If the code does not work as expected using the compiler Turbo C++ then try to initialize the pointer to the head node explicitly

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node *prev;
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} *head = NULL, *temp, *temp1;
```

Comment: I Tried But the Same Result

Comment: @KarthikAnurag I do not see where redundant nodes can be added.

Comment: @KarthikAnurag See my appended answer.

Comment: I Tried It I Initialized all Used Pointers to Null After Declaration. It didnt help

Comment: @KarthikAnurag Do you have done exactly as I showed in my answer? If so then in this case I can say nothing what is the problem.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/hvmENBHbSGHzMrdi9
Check This is My Output

Comment: Check My New Code

Comment: @KarthikAnurag : Did you make the change in this answer that explicitly sets head to NULL by changing `} *head , *temp, *temp1;" to `} *head = NULL, *temp, *temp1;`? I tried it here on Turbo-C with all the changes including the last one and it works.

Comment: Okay I see the updated code in your question. You still didn't fix `ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));` to be `ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

Comment: @KarthikAnurag And what is head->next->prev = ptr;?!! Can you do the changes I showed?!

Comment: @KarthikAnurag : I'm using Turbo-C++ 3.00 here and with the changes suggested in this answer it works. Are you sure you have all the changes and are you sure you are compiling and running the right program?

Comment: Thank You @VladfromMoscow It Worked. But I Still Didn't Understand Why to assign ptr = (struct Noed *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Comment: @KarthikAnurag You need to allocate memory for an object of the type struct Node where data will be stored.